# How to clean up internet explorer cookies programmatically?

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

How to clean up internet explorer cookies programmatically?

Is there some windows API function to do it?

Comment: Acutually I'm looking for a windows API function solution. But I will use it in VB6.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I got it!

In Windows API you have a function to create cookies called [**`InternetSetCookie`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385326(VS.85).aspx), and you use it like this:

```
InternetSetCookie("http://teste.com", NULL, "name = value; expires = Sat,01-Jan-2020 00:00:00 GMT");
```

But, if you want to delete the cookie instead of creating it, you just have to set the expiration field somewhere in the past, like this:

```
InternetSetCookie("http://teste.com", NULL, "name = value; expires = Sat,01-Jan-2000 00:00:00 GMT");
```

More info about it in [**Managing Cookies**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385326(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you just search `C:\Documents and Settings\user\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files` for files with 'cookie' in the filename?

Here's the Win32 call to get the folder:

```
BOOL SHGetSpecialFolderPath(
  HWND hwndOwner,
  LPTSTR lpszPath,
  int nFolder,
  BOOL fCreate 
);
```

Pass `CSIDL_COOKIES` as the `nFolder` argument.

Check this link out [A Cleanup API for Windows](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Cleanup_API.aspx?display=Print#cookies_cleanup).

You can delete cached cookies via the `FindFirstUrlCacheEntry`,`FindNextUrlCacheEntry` and `DeleteUrlCacheEntry` functions. You can pass 'cookie:' as the first argument (`LPCTSTR  lpszUrlSearchPattern`) to `FindFirstUrlCacheEntry`.

Comment: This is a very very ugly workaround. You could delete the files theoretically, but while Internet Explorer is running it will not notice that. The correct way is to use an API for that (as correctly answered by Daniel)